# React will not pass props to API link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

http://codepen.io/beckbeach/pen/mWqrep My codepen

React will not pass the props to ${this.state.query} in my API link. What am i doing wrong?

```
class App extends React.Component {                                  
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
query: ''
  }
 }

 searchFunction() {
    fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${this.state.query},us&appid=748f643131acee33c207bee1a969f6e3', {
  method: 'GET'
}).then((res) => {
res.json().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  })
 })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
  })
   }

 render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Check The Weather!</h1>
    <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Zipcode" value={this.state.query} onChange={event => {this.setState({query: event.target.value})}}  />
<button type="submit" onClick={() => this.searchFunction()}>CHECK WEATHER </button>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: FWIW, this has nothing to do with React itself. You are not using template literals correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Your using a single quote instead of back ticks for the template literal.

```
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${this.state.query},us&appid=748f643131acee33c207bee1a969f6e3'
```

should be

```
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${this.state.query},us&appid=748f643131acee33c207bee1a969f6e3`
```

info on template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick () (grave accent)
>   character instead of double or single quotes. Template literals can
>   contain place holders. These are indicated by the Dollar sign and
>   curly braces (${expression}). The expressions in the place holders and
>   the text between them get passed to a function. The default function
>   just concatenates the parts into a single string. If there is an
>   expression preceding the template literal (tag here),  the template
>   string is called "tagged template literal". In that case, the tag
>   expression (usually a function) gets called with the processed
>   template literal, which you can then manipulate before outputting. To
>   escape a back-tick in a template literal, put a backslash \ before the
>   back-tick.

working pen http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/MpONrW